# change textbox width based on it's value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, textbox, width

I am trying to change my textbox's width according to textbox's value but it does not seems like working. 
Here is my aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtbSizeOzel" runat="server" CssClass="text-center"></asp:TextBox>$
```

I create an onKeyUp event for resizing method in codebehind:

```
TxtbSizeOzel.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "Expand(this)");
```

And lastly my javascript method:

```
function Expand(obj)
 {
   if (!obj.savesize) obj.savesize = obj.size;
    obj.size = Math.max(obj.savesize, obj.value.length);
 }
```

I don't get any error but it just doesn't working.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED WITH CODE EXPLANATION:

here you go, the input will always be as long as its characters, whether you type, remove or give it a value before running the script: [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/y4wc92j3/1/)

```
//this is a plugin snippet (or function) to check if the element has
//horizontal scrollbar
$.fn.hasHorizontalScrollBar = function() {
  if (this[0].clientWidth < this[0].scrollWidth) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
//the end of plugin

var originalWidth=$('.txt').width(); //we store the original width
//(the width of the input at the page load) in a variable to use it as a 
//measurement in order to not let the input get smaller than this size 

//this function checks the width of `.txt` (the input) to see if it has 
//horizontal scrollbar or not, if it does then expands the width of the input to
//the scroll size, else it checks to see if the width is added to the 
//original width, if so, removes one character (depending on the font size it'll
//change - here it is 7 px)
function changeWidth(){
    if($('.txt').hasHorizontalScrollBar()){
        $('.txt').width(document.getElementsByClassName('txt')[0].scrollWidth);
    }
    else if(originalWidth<$('.txt').width()){
        $('.txt').width($('.txt').width()-7);
    }
};
//end of the function

changeWidth(); //run the function at page load, to give the input a size as wide as its
// character's length

$('.txt').keydown(changeWidth); //assign the function to the keydown event of the input
//so whenever a character is added or removed the function will run again
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) property of JQuery. It supports the `get` and `set` operations for width manipulation of controls or elements in your HTML.

And you can try this if you want to go with JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById("yourControlId").style.width = "300px";
```

Hope this helps.